# Monks, their hospitalization and their medical treatment

Tags: buddha, monasticism, vinaya, killing

I have questions regarding hospitalization and its morals

1. Are monks/nuns allowed to be hospitalized and can they go to a hospital or doctor if sick? (because aren't they not allowed to request anything according to the vinaya?)
2. Can a monk/nun take painkillers or will that be a breach of the fifth precept?
3. If there is a parasite or other being inside of someone, can they take medicine to cure themselves of it, or would that break the first precept, or is it not if the being isn't sentient?

Comment: Have you read Vinaya Pitaka?https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/index.html

Comment: 1. Exept if biten by snake, they can not ask for it, but if invited, given, yes. 2. They are allowed to accept pain reducing medicine. 3. Difficult. Depends on ones perception.

Answer (score 2):

When I lived in Thailand:

1. Monks were admitted to hospital.
2. Monks took painkillers.
3. Monks used medicine for internal parasites.

Answer (score 0):

Medicine is one of the only possessions a monk can “desire” and can dedicate their time to procuring. Suchly are medical needs to be given priority and utmost attention.

Answer (score 0):

Go and see a doctor.  No amount of pondering or meditation will help you if you are very sick/dead.

Comment: That isn't what the Buddha taught, good householder, but the opposite, since sickness and death are actually unavoidable.

Comment: Yes, but sickness is curable.  Unless Buddha a against that as well?

Comment: His path leads to lasting cure and he wouldn't send one off searching heal in where it can not be found. So saying his path is useless, seek for usual ways is a strange answer under the topic Buddha.

Comment: But does it?  Really?  And if so, has it been backed up by lots of medical studies?  The  questioner is asking in regards to the precepts and not about whether any magical healing powers will save him. If someone is ill and you tell them NOT to get treatment you could get into trouble.  Also, every other answer here seems to agree with me.

Comment: There isn't any being which will not get old, sick and die, but it pretty normal that beings seek refuge where there is no. Less benefit if answering questions and not familare with the matter at all, yet thinking smart as well. May good householder go on as he feels fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain there is a jataka where a monk with worms is given medicine causing him to vomit.

Didn't take note of the reference.